# how to add time plus and recalculate the datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, increment

i have this datetime format:

```
Oct 31, 2012 08:59:52
```

i would like to re-calculate the  datetime incremented (for example) of 2 hours or 50 minutes plus how can i do that?

i need to return the same datetime format showed above and not a timestamp!

Comment: `date.setTime(date.getTime() + milliseconds);`

Comment: i need to return to the datetime format i'm using not to timestamp

Comment: Are you trying to change just the string or an actual bonefied date() object in javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var date = new Date("Oct 31, 2012 08:59:52");
var timeInMillis = date.getTime();
```

Now that you have time in milliseconds, you can just add the time you want in millis.

Eg: 2 hours? So, 2*60*60*1000 + timeInMillis

```
var newDate = new Date(2*60*60*1000 + timeInMillis);
```

If you want to convert your newDate into the original format, which is a long process, you can some guidance from here:

[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

My pick of the answers would be:

Use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: yes but i need to return to the format i have , not needed timestamp date format

Answer (score 1):

You could first parse this to a date:

```
var d=new Date("October 31, 2012 08:59:25").getTime();
```

Then add the offset:

```
d+= (seconds)*1000 + (minutes)*60000 + (hours)*3600000;
var result = new Date(d);
```

I am just not sure wether it accepts 'Oct' instead of 'October'

Answer (score 0):

```
time_start = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
time_finish = new Date() - time_start;
```

Set the Date using the format listed above. To calculate the interval between two points of time, just subtract the current date from the past date.